# Redirecting PayPal checkout straight to the guest checkout

Tags: paypal

Trying to link directly to the guest checkout page and avoid the login screen entirely. Currently it is redirecting to a
[login page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RTXzD.png)

But I would like to skip that step entirely and go straight to the [guest checkout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VM29r.png)

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please post the code you have already written to solve your problem and tellus what you have already tried and tell us more details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you can do is instead integrate PayPal Checkout with a black "Debit or Credit Card" button.

Here is a basic demo: https://developer.paypal.com/demo/checkout/#/pattern/client